# Append extra data in the chart after selecting new item from a dropdown in JSF

Tags: jsf, drop-down-menu

I am using highcharts to generate chart based on selecting items in a dropdown list. When I select first item from the dropdown it is showing correct data. When I select second item from the dropdown it is also showing correct data. But when I select first item from the dropdown again then it is appending few data with the first chart.

For example: first dropdown item has 1000 data points. Second dropdown item has 1500 data points. When I select first item of the dropdown after selecting second item of the dropdown then the first 1000 data points are correct but it also append 500 abnormal data in the chart. Because the second item hase 1500 data points in total. The first item always get teh size of the second item when I select second item.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing the chart we need to empty the array. This will solve the problem.

If we pass chartData as an array to the highcharts then at the end of the highchart we can use chartData.length = 0. This will make the array empty and when we will select a new item from the dropdown it will get the new size of the selected item.

Thanks